# Undefined reference to 'SDL_main' in Dev c++

Tags: c++, sdl

i am currently having problem compiling my project in dev c++, what i did was i accidently pressed 'Rebuild all' instead of compile and run and now it is showing this error.

`Undefined Reference to 'SDL_main'` , what can i do in order to fix this error?

Comment: @PaulR that dupe target does not have an answer

Comment: @NathanOliver: true, but it's the same question from the same poster, so the preferred course of action is to go back and improve the original question rather than just re-posting it.

Comment: @PaulR Didn't notice it was the same user.  nvm.

Comment: Note that there are tons of other duplicates and near duplicates for this question too - it would have been quicker and easier to just search for the solution than post another question.

Answer (score 2):

This error is common when using `int main()` instead of :

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
//or
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Try replacing it with either of these.

**Edit:** After seeing the question you asked two days ago about he same issue, I will add some clarification :

- When you create your project, make sure you choose a `Win32 GUI` or `Win32 Console` application.
- After creating your project, I assume you added the following command line to your project parameters under linker : `-lmingw32 - -lSD2main -lSDL2`
- Then put `SDL2.dll` in your project directory where your executable will be.
- Include `SDL2.h` before `main(int argc, char **argv)` begins in your source code.